# Django Queryset for Getting Feeds from Following Users

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to get feeds from following users such as Facebook, Instagram, and Twitter. I wrote a view to show feeds from following people.

```
class Following(View):
    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        posts =  models.Post.objects.filter(creator__in=user.following.all()).order_by('created_date')[:5]
```

I was worrying if it might cause a performance issue due to user.following.all() part. I do not know why

```
filter(creator=user.following)
```

does not work.

following is a self-referencing ManyToManyField.

```
followers = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
following = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
```

Is there any better solution?

I have another issues with counting a number of ManyToManyFields.

```
class Popular(View):
    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        posts = models.Post.objects.annotate(number_of_likes=Count('likes'), number_of_comments=Count('comments')).filter(Q(channels__users=user) & (Q(number_of_likes__gte=5) | Q(number_of_comments__gte=5))).order_by('created_date')[:5]
```

It is so long because likes__count and comments__count did not work. The only case I found on the internet that works was this, using annotate(). Is there a better solution for this? I want to filter out posts that have channels a user is subscribing and among them, I want to only show number of likes or number of comments are above certain range. Why does this not work?

```
models.Post.objects.filter(Q(channels__users=user) & (Q(likes__count__gte=5) | Q(comments__count__gte=5))).order_by('created_date')[:5]

class Comment(news_models.TimeStampedModel):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
class Like(news_models.TimeStampedModel):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='likes')
class Channel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='channels')
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post, related_name='channels')
```

Comment: Using a double `ManyToManyField` is rather strange, if a person follows a certain user, he is a follower I think, so I would first fix the modeling issue, then this is a rather simple problem.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You are right. I changed it tofollowers = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, related_name='following', symmetrical=False) Still, it doesn't change the fact that I have to filter out people who an user follows by using creator__in=user.following.all()

Comment: you can just filter like `.filter(creator__followers=user)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh, you are absolutely right! Thank you!! Do you have any suggestion for the second query in a function Popular?